# Making a custom Log During Coded Ui Test Run

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

basically I am running a set of coded ui tests using MStest.

I am trying to write a custom log file while the tests are running.

For instance at the end of every test, if the test has passed I want to add a line to a text file that says "Test  has passed"

This would preferable go out to a TXT file.
and by extension i will eventually be outputting this to an email but that isnt needed right now.

On a basic level at the end of each test i was trying this

```
 if (this.testContextInstance.CurrentTestOutcome.Equals(true))
        {
            string lines = "Passed.";
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\test.txt");
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            string lines = "Failed.";
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\test.txt");
            file.WriteLine(lines);
            file.Close();
        }
    }
```

But I don't fully understand the CurrentTestOutcome method.

At the moment i'm not getting any file output at all.

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentTestOutcome` is an enum see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.currenttestoutcome.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.unittestoutcome.aspx . So I am not sure what the `this.testContextInstance.CurrentTestOutcome.Equals(true)` of the question achieves.

Something like the following should show what you want:

```
string lines = "Failed.";
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(this.testContextInstance.CurrentTestOutcome.ToString());
file.Close();
```